# How come matlab run slower and slower when running a program that takes long time to execute?

Tags: performance, matlab, slowdown

There is a program that my matlab runs, since there are two gigantic nested for-loop, we expect this program to run more than 10 hours. We ask matlab to print out the loop number every time when it is looping.

Initially (the first 1 hour), wee see the loop number increment very fast in our screen; as time goes by, it goes slower and slower..... now (more than 20 consecutive hours of executing the same ".m" file and it still haven't finished yet), it is almost 20 times slower than it had been initially.

The ram usage initially was about 30%, right now after 20 hours of executing time, it is as shown below: [image]

---

My computer spec is below. [image]

**What can I do to let matlab maintain its initially speed?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only guess, but my bet is that you have some array variables that **have not been preallocated**, and thus their size increases at each iteration of the `for` loop. As a result of this, Matlab has to **reallocate memory in each iteration**. Reallocating slows things down, and **more so the larger those variables are**, because Matlab needs to find an ever larger chunk of contiguous memory. This would explain why the program seems to run slower as time passes.

If this is indeed the cause, the solution would be to preallocate those variables. If their size is not known beforehand, you can make a guess and preallocate to an **approximate** size, thus avoiding at least some of the reallocating. Or, if your program is not memory-limited, maybe you can use an **upper-bound** on variable size when preallocating; then, after the loop, trim the arrays by removing unused entries.

Comment: @andy_tse. If this is the cause, adding the command [`pack`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pack.html) at the beginning of your loop will consolidate the memory (defragment it basically). It will introduce a small overhead but it is worth testing because the next iteration will be more likely to find contiguous space in memory.

Comment: @Hoki AFAIK you can call `pack` only from scripts and not from functions.

Comment: @Shai. My bad, you are totally right. `pack` will not work inside a function. _Although if desired, the same functionality can be obtained by doing it manually (save workspace or bulky variables/clear/reload). This [post](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/292307) on matlab central give the details._

Answer (score 4):

Some general hints, if they don't help I suggest to add the code to the question.

1. Don't print to console, this output slows down execution and the output is kept in memory. Write a logfile instead if you need it. For a simple status, use `waitbar`
2. Verify you are preallocating all variables
3. Check which function calls depend on the loop index, for example increasing size of variables.
4. If any mex-functions are used, double check them for memory leaks. The standard procedure to do this: Call the function with random example data, don't store the output. If the memory usage increases there is a memory leak in the function.
5. Use the profiler. Profile your code for the first n iterations (where n matches about 10 minutes), generate a HTML report. Then let it run for about 2 hours and generate a report for n iterations again. Now compare both reports and see where the time is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point everybody to the following page in the MATLAB documentation: [Strategies for Efficient Use of Memory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html). This page contains a collection of techniques and good practices that MATLAB users should be aware of.

The OP reminded me of it when saying that memory usage tends to increase over time. Indeed there's an issue with long running instances of MATLAB on **win32** systems, where a memory leak exists and is exacerbated over time (this is described in the link too).

I'd like to add to **Luis'** answer the following piece of advice that a friend of mine once received during a correspondence with Yair Altman:

> Allocating **largest vars first** helps by assigning the largest free contiguous blocks to the highest vars, but it is easily shown that in some cases this can actually be harmful, so it is not a general solution.
>
> The only sure way to solve memory fragmentation is by restarting Matlab and even better to restart Windows.

More information on memory allocation performance can be found in the following undocumentedMatlab posts:

- [Preallocation performance](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/)
- [Allocation performance take 2](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/allocation-performance-take-2)

Comment: "_but it is easily shown that in some cases this can actually be harmful_". I am curious as why would that be harmful (and in which cases) ? The article you link does not mention this danger.

Comment: @Hoki - I am not familiar with such an "easy explanation". I did however added a couple links to my answer with a bit more information regarding preallocation performance.